# nodejs - MQTT connection always drops while subscribing to a topic

Tags: node.js, mqtt, aws-iot, subscribe

I am using MQTT node module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt), with mqtts type of connection with key, certificate and CA. The connection happens and the connected event is triggered. However, always while subscribing to a topic the connection closes.

Code for connection:

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");  //also tried async version and same problem

this._client = mqtt.connect(
  'mqtts://' + this._iotUrl,
   {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(this._certPath),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(this._caPath),
    key: fs.readFileSync(this._keyPath),
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    clientId: clientId,
    clean: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    resubscribe: true
  });
```

Code for subscription:

```
this._client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("client connected!! %s", clientId);
    this._client.subscribe('"test/topic"', { qos: 1 }, (err, granted) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("topic subscription: granted ", granted, err,);
         } else {
             console.log("granted: ", granted);
          }
      });
 });
```

Result of execution:

```
======== Starting MQTT Client ==========

client connection request
starting run function 
client connected!! mqttjs_bw5yymezc
topic subscription: granted  [ { topic: '"test/topic"', qos: 1 } ] Error: Connection closed
    at /Users/<user>/<project>/src/shared/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:124:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at flushVolatile (/Users/<user><project>/src/shared/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:122:24)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/<project>/src/shared/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:358:5)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at net.js:673:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:563:7)
client connected!! mqttjs_bw5yymezc
granted:  []
```

According to my options defined in mqtt connection, it continues trying to connect again, and the same happens every time. There is no helpful message or feedback in the error to try to pinpoint the issue. Also tried to use mqtt debug and see exactly the same.

**EXTRA INFORMATION**

To be able to subscribe to the topics using the certificate, a policy was set up and attached to the certificate.
This "should be" correct because last week until Friday I was able to connect/subscribe/publish without problems.

To try to identify the issue, I even try many things with the policy. The policy current state:

```
{
    Version: '2012-10-17',
    Statement: [
        {
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Action: ["iot:Connect"],
            Resource: [
                "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:client/mqttjs_*",
            ]

        },
        {
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Action: ["iot:Subscribe"],
            Resource: [
                "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:topicfilter/application/topic/#/test",
                //"arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:topic/test/topic",
            ]

        },
        {
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Action: ["iot:Publish"],
            Resource: [
                "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:topic/test/topic",
            ]

        },
    ],
}
```

Additionally, I even tried using aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 (https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2), a module that already facilitates all the MQTT functionality. I tested the pub/sub sample, just passing url, key, certificate and ca path (same used in the code above))in the command line (example bellow). I could connect and see the subscribe and publish last week. Now the connection also drops.

Executing aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 with pub/sub sample:

```
node dist/index.js --endpoint <aws_iot_endpoint> --ca_file "<path>/cert/AmazonRootCA1-dev.pem" --cert "<path>/cert/certificate_generated.pem.crt" --key "/<path>/cert/private_generated.pem.key"
```

What can be causing this connection issue?
Someone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: This is going to be a problem with the cert/IAM permissions

Comment: What does the MQTT Broker log file say? If you get a connection, there should be something about that, and what follows that will tell you what is going on.  Like hardillb, I think this is a cert issue of some sort.

Comment: First issue that I've noticed is that you use '"test/topic"' in the topic of the subscribe method. Should be "test/topic" or 'test/topic'. Second, could be the subscription policy as well. 
Did you face the same with "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:topic/test/topic" or "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:<AWS_client>:topicfilter/test/topic" in topic policies?

Comment: you were right, I was missing the topic filter on subscribe :) thank you all